# Output buffer based progress bar

Tags: php

I have been trying to get the following code working.

It's a progress bar trick which uses ob_get_clean() function.

Don't know why but this script just don't work!

Only the initial percent - 1% comes up and nothing after that.

```
<?php  
error_reporting(8191);  
function flush_buffers(){  
    @ob_end_flush();  
    @ob_flush();  
    @flush();  
    @ob_start();
} 
$ini    =   2;
echo '<script>document.getElementById(\'lpt\').style.width=\'1%\';</script><br>';  
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)  {
            $k=$ini-1;
            $str=str_replace("width=\'$k%\'","width=\'$i%\'",ob_get_clean());           
            $ini++;
            echo $str;
            flush_buffers();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't *'retract'* output text after you've sent it to the client. It merely gets appended.

Answer (score 1):

It would not work as you are trying to mix server and client side code. PHP Code on the client side would not work. You will need to build the whole progress bar using javascript itself.

Comment: i would think that this is possible using flex but i am not very sure.

Answer (score 1):

What @Delan says: You can't "take back" and edit output that has already been sent to the client. You would have to output a completely new `<script>` snippet for every movement of the percentage bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do progress bar in PHP, you must write in eg. JavaScript, and only echo with PHP.
You can't do that because PHP is *server-side* language and any loading is performing on *client-side* because server don't loads anything then loading script you must have in *client-side* language.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think any of these answers are complete or correct that are up-voted.

it's true that you can't retract output, but you CAN do what KPL wants to do using a simplistic non-ajax approach that doesn't even require javascript... i do this all the time.  tested on ie 9, firefox, chrome and safari.  perhaps it could be true that in 2010 when this was asked this technique didn't work, but i don't see why now.  it's not html5 or anything fancy...

you do so using ob_flush like KPL guesses and you re-output the current bar html (however you like it to look, fancy/animated/etc) with position:absolute and an incrementing z-index:$counter.  that way on each loop the output gets flushed as the php is running on the server and the new output is neatly placed over top of the previous output.  sounds messy, but this technique looks perfect and works really really well on every browser i've tried.